# display Every day & date behind in pop up browser window after clicking button that asks it on main window

Tags: javascript

[Example of the goal of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8REa.png)

I have a project at school.
When we click on a button in the main window we need to display al the days af the month. example: sunday 23/10/2016.
this needs to start from the first day an has to end on the last day.
If we should use the same button on in a diferent month then that needs to be shown.
I have tried to get it but no luck so far.

this a bit of code i have tried already.

```
function maandLijst() {

    var nieuwvenster = window.open("", "", "Height=200, Width=50")
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

    nieuwvenster.document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
}
```

this is in the .js file.
I tried to add some cases but had no luck so far.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Comment: Can you add what you've tried so far to your question? Where should the days of the months  be displayed and what do you think it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you could use a `for` loop in your function:

```
<html>
<body>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="maandLijst();" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function maandLijst() {

    var nieuwvenster = window.open("", "", "Height=200, Width=50")
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    //var day = currentTime.getDate()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

    for (var day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
        nieuwvenster.document.writeln(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Still to be done: replace 31 by the actual amount of days in that specific month and add the name of the day of the week.